# After code is Compiled and ran, data is entered, then nothing. There should be a table printed out with all the information

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am a student taking a C++ class, My professor has videos for each lab and examples which help. I have finished this example from our textbook and watched his videos to make sure my code matches (to my knowledge it does). There is supposed to be a table showing up at the very end of the code but nothing happens. It just goes blank. I know there are a few other issues with the code like small errors that do not affect the main processes only mathematical which I will fix. I just need to see the table to troubleshoot. I have tried to debug with the console but it shows nothing is wrong. What small detail have I missed or messed up? I also do not need the code to be easier, I know that I can word it differently or use different processes, but this is what my professor is having us do not much freedom with it.

```
// Author: Danny lee Cornelius
// Date: 4/4/2022
// Program Description: Chap8lab

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 6;

//Function Prototypes
void getData(double list[], int length);
void avgSpeedOverTime(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[]);
double maxAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length);
double minAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length);
void print(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[]);

int main()
{
    //Define arrays
    double distTraveled[SIZE];
    double averageSpeed[SIZE];
    
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    
    getData(distTraveled, SIZE);
    avgSpeedOverTime(distTraveled, SIZE, averageSpeed);
    print(distTraveled, SIZE, averageSpeed);
    
    cout << "Maximum average speed: " << maxAvgSpeed(averageSpeed, SIZE) << endl;
    cout << "Minimum average speed: " << minAvgSpeed(averageSpeed, SIZE) << endl;

   //system("Pause");
   return 0;
}

void getData(double list[], int length)
{
    cout << "Enter the total distance traveled after "
         << "every 10 units of time.\n";
    
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        cout << "Enter total distance traveled at time "
             << index + 10 << " units: ";
        cin >> list[index];
    }
}

void avgSpeedOverTime(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[])
{
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        avgSpeed[index] = (list[index = 1] - list[index]) /10;
    }
}

double maxAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length)
{
    double max = avgSpeed[0];
    
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if (avgSpeed[index] > max)
            max = avgSpeed[index];
    }
}

double minAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length)
{
    double min = avgSpeed[0];
    
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if (avgSpeed[index] < min)
            min = avgSpeed[index];
    }
}

void print(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[])
{
    cout << setw(7) << "Time " << setw(20) << "Distance Traveled  "
         << setw(10) << "Average Speed / Time Interval" << endl;
         
    cout << setw(5) << 0
         << setw(14) << list[0] << setw(6) << " "
         << setw(10) << 0 << "  [0, 0] " << endl;
    
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << index * 10
         << setw(14) << list[index] << setw(6) << " "
         << setw(10) << avgSpeed[index - 1]
         << "  [" << (index + 1) * 10 << ", "
         << index * 10 << "]" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a typo at `avgSpeed[index] = (list[index = 1] - list[index]) /10;` But if you fix that and try to read `list[index - 1]` when `index = 0`, you have another problem.

Comment: Side note: you have a couple of functions that declare they return a value but don't return anything. Ex: `double minAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length)` does not `return` anything.

Comment: Due to those functions that are supposed to return a value not actually returning a value, the program is broken at runtime.  So expect anything to happen, including not printing.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp -- That isn't a side note.  That may be *the* reason why things are not working correctly.

Comment: *"I am a student [...] and watched his videos to make sure my code matches (to my knowledge it does)."* -- how does any of this help someone understand what your question is? Please review [ask], in particular the parts about getting to the point so that people can quickly triage questions, picking out the ones in their area of knowledge/experience. You should start with your question, and save your background and excuses for either the end of the question or the cutting room floor.

Comment: *"I know there are a few other issues with the code like small errors that do not affect the main processes"* -- sounds like you have code in your **example** that could be taken out. Please do so (and perhaps review [mre] -- questions should contain a demonstration of your issue, not a full solution to whatever your teacher assigned you).

Answer (score 0):

If you ask your compiler to warn you about possible errors, e.g.
`-std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fsanitize=undefined`,
you get the following compiler output (for gcc):

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/G5fhehdbP)

```
<source>: In function 'void avgSpeedOverTime(double*, int, double*)':
<source>:55:39: error: operation on 'index' may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
   55 |         avgSpeed[index] = (list[index = 1] - list[index]) /10;
      |                                 ~~~~~~^~~
<source>:55:39: error: operation on 'index' may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
<source>: In function 'double maxAvgSpeed(double*, int)':
<source>:68:1: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
   68 | }
      | ^
<source>: In function 'double minAvgSpeed(double*, int)':
<source>:79:1: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
   79 | }
      | ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Advising about:

1. An `index = 1` assignment at a `list[index = 1]` expression.
   Were you meaning to do a `list[index - 1]` instead?
2. Two functions that should return something but have no return statement.

---

The code below may be a possible fix (I'm not sure it does exactly what you are asked to do).
It uses the `fmt` library instead of `std::cout` and `<iomanip>` (what may produce clearer code; again, I don't know if you'll be able to use it for this assignment):

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/EfKerfWzs)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>  // cin

const int SIZE = 6;

// Function prototypes
void getData(double list[], int length);
void avgSpeedOverTime(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[]);
double maxAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length);
double minAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length);
void print(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[]);

int main() {
    // Define arrays
    double distTraveled[SIZE];
    double averageSpeed[SIZE];
    
    getData(distTraveled, SIZE);
    avgSpeedOverTime(distTraveled, SIZE, averageSpeed);
    print(distTraveled, SIZE, averageSpeed);
    
    fmt::print("Maximum average speed: {:.2f}\n", maxAvgSpeed(averageSpeed, SIZE));
    fmt::print("Minimum average speed: {:.2f}\n", minAvgSpeed(averageSpeed, SIZE));
}

void getData(double list[], int length) {
    fmt::print("Enter the total distance traveled after every 10 units of time.\n\n");    
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        fmt::print("Enter total distance traveled at time {} units: ", index + 10);
        std::cin >> list[index];
        fmt::print("{}\n", list[index]);
    }
}

void avgSpeedOverTime(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[]) {
    avgSpeed[0] = (list[0] - 0) / 10;
    for (int index = 1; index < length; index++) {
        avgSpeed[index] = (list[index] - list[index - 1]) / 10;
    }
}

double maxAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length) {
    double max = avgSpeed[0];    
    for (int index = 1; index < length; index++) {
        if (avgSpeed[index] > max) {
            max = avgSpeed[index];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

double minAvgSpeed(double avgSpeed[], int length) {
    double min = avgSpeed[0];
    for (int index = 1; index < length; index++) {
        if (avgSpeed[index] < min) {
            min = avgSpeed[index];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

void print(double list[], int length, double avgSpeed[]) {
    fmt::print("\n{:>5}{:>20}{:>32}\n",
        "Time",
        "Distance Traveled",
        "Average Speed / Time Interval");
         
    fmt::print("{:5}{:20}{:16}{:8}[ 0,  0]\n",
        0,
        0,
        0,
        ' ');
    
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        fmt::print("{:5}{:20}{:16.2f}{:8}[{:2}, {:2}]\n",
            (index + 1) * 10,
            list[index],
            avgSpeed[index],
            ' ',
            index * 10,
            (index + 1) * 10);
    }
    fmt::print("\n");
}

// Input:
//
//   4
//   9
//   15
//   22
//   30
//   39
//
// Output:
//
//    Time   Distance Traveled   Average Speed / Time Interval
//       0                   0               0        [ 0,  0]
//      10                   4            0.40        [ 0, 10]
//      20                   9            0.50        [10, 20]
//      30                  15            0.60        [20, 30]
//      40                  22            0.70        [30, 40]
//      50                  30            0.80        [40, 50]
//      60                  39            0.90        [50, 60]
//   
//   Maximum average speed: 0.90
//   Minimum average speed: 0.40
```